# Load string with Html tags

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

I am loading a string into UIwebview. The string is a simple text coming from Database. What I want is that webview should show the text in Bold. How to add HTML `<b>` tag or any tag to this simple text coming from Database ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to wrap the whole string in <b></b>, you can do it like this:

```
NSString *wrappedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<b>%@</b>", stringFromDatabase];
```